# WPF application not picking up Segoe UI Symbol font

Tags: wpf, fonts, symbols

I have a WPF application, running on 64-bit Windows 7, wherein I am using Segoe UI Symbol font. It works perfectly fine on my box, but the font doesn't show up on a similar dev box (64-bit Windows 7).

I verified, the problem box has this font installed on it.

Could anyone kindly guide me what could be the cause of this behaviour?

Thanks,

RDV

Comment: Copy the font from a box where the font is working and then reinstall the font.  I am not guessing here.  That is exactly what I have had to do more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another legal :-) way - (just have to figure out doing it via ClickOnce or Windows MSI installer) to install a newer version of a given font.

There are two solutions:

1. Delete the older font version via registry and then install the newer version- manually or via msi installer. More information on deleting the font via registry can be found here: http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Protected-System-Fonts-in-Windows-7

   Pros: All can be done via scripts/installer.

   Cons: Messing with Registry keys.
2. Another option is to provide full privilege to the currently logged in user (pay attention- logged in user may not be the administrator on the box) on the said font and then delete the font. Install the newer Font version - manually or via installer. More information on providing privilege can be found here: http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/39842-protected-system-fonts.html

   Pros: Cleaner way for doing things manually.

   Cons: Do not know how to provide privilege via script/installer.

Thanks,

RDV

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Blam & HighCore for your inputs.

I figured out that Windows 7 has Segoe UI Symbol Regular font of version 5.0. WPF applications require min version 5.01 of this font.

Thanks,
RDV

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally found a way to use the newer version of "Segoe UI Symbol" even when older version is installed (i.e. on Windows 7). The idea is to create a copy of the font file with a different name. This approach works also in ClickOnce installation and requires no bootstrapping.

It is posted on this link: [Embedded Font in WPF not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893433/embedded-font-in-wpf-not-working/27911618)

Comment: Renaming the font works, but as PatrickV mentioned, it might not be legal.- RDV

Answer (score 0):

Segoe UI Symbol is NOT installed by default on Windows 7. You need to either

1 - [Embed the font in your application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

or

2 - [Manually deploy to all target machines](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2729094)